# Pushing API Gateway "API Keys" using API Gateway SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a set of Apigateway API Keys in a file in S3. I want to create a small POC which would read the file from S3 and push the API Keys to the API Gateway "API Keys" and associate the same with respective usage plan.

But I cannot find any method which kind of pushes/puts (something like putApiKey()) in the SDK. Not Sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. There is a method **importApiKeys(ImportApiKeysRequest request)** in the sdk itself, which Imports API keys from an external source, such as a CSV-formatted file.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a small POC which would read the file from S3 and
>   push the API Keys to the API Gateway "API Keys"

[Here is an API action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#importApiKeys-property) available in AWS JS SDK to import API keys.

> and associate the same with respective usage plan

[Here is an API action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#createUsagePlanKey-property) available in AWS JS SDK for adding an existing API key to a usage plan.